# How to update a column in the database using SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having two tables, in one of the table I am inserting the data and in the other table I want to update a single column. But if I use update, it is updating all the columns in that table. It is inserting correctly. Can any one help me?

```
$this->db->trans_begin();       
$data=array(
    'company_name'=>$this->input->post('company_name'),
    'category_id'=>$this->input->post('category_id'),
    'quantity_rec'=>$this->input->post('quantity_rec'),
     );

$this->db->insert('inventory',$data);
$a=$this->input->post('quantity_rec');
$b=$this->input->post('stock');

$c=$a+$b;

$data1=array(    
      'stock'=>$c,
      );

$this->db->where(array('department_category.category_id'=>$id));
$this->db->update('department_category',$data1);
$this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this ?

Comment: sql  first iam assinging those values to a variables by using that iam doing addition and i need to update only  that cloumn

Comment: show your update query

Comment: query i has changed see above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$this->db->update('department_category',$data1);
```

should have parameter where

```
$this->db->where(somewhere);
```

if no well, u change entire data dude

Comment: in the above query if i wont use where function it is  updating the total data present in that table,but if i use where function it is not updating getting error as unknown column 0 in where clause

Comment: can anyone help me this please

Comment: if u got unknown column in where clause, mean there is no collumn in table u usign where.